# How to parse Document to Json - Mongo scala driver

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

I'm using play framework and mongo scala driver to set a database up, I need to parse the result of a query to Json to send it to the front-end:

```
def getAllProcess(userId: String) = {
    getCollection(COMPANY_FORM).find(equal("userId", userId)).subscribe(new Observer[Document] {
      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println(e)

      override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Complete")

      override def onNext(result: Document): Unit = println(result)
    })
  }
```

How to parse its result ?

Comment: You can start by converting the result of the query to a Future so you can map the data and pass it as need be. Subscribers aren't very useful in idiomatic Scala

Comment: It's impossible in this case to return a future

Comment: Try `getCollection(COMPANY_FORM).find(equal("userId", userId)).toFuture()`. Then you can either pipe it into something that takes Futures or call Await.result() and get the result to pass it to the play framework. I'm not familiar with how the play framework works